# Llamar a boton create en vista MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-core

seguramente sea una tontería la pregunta, pero no encuentro forma de llamar a un botón desde la vista MVC, me explico:

Lo que quiero es que automáticamente se pulse el botón de "create" cuando la página se cargue con los valores necesarios. para que veais el flujo, pongo el código:

Aquí llamo a la accion "Create" que me pone los valores donde toca

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "Creados",
  new
  {
      // Lista de argumentos
  }
```

Después, una vez en la vista MVC...

```
// Falta todo el código restante que son solo asignaciones.

<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SalarioReal" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="SalarioReal" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="SalarioReal" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="crt" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div>
  <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Mi duda es como podría llamar automáticamente al botón:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="crt" />
```

Para que fuera transparente al ususario la inserción de los datos en la BD puesto que ya relleno todos los campos desde otra vista.

Un saludo, muchas gracias!!

P.D: He probado con:

```
@Html.Partial("Create")
```

Y me retorna a la misma vista a la que estoy. Lo que deseo es ir a la acción "Create", pero la que tiene el tag [HttPost], es decir, esta:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("los argumentos que sean...")] Creados creados)
```

Comment: Has probado a enviarlo desde javascript?

Comment: Hola Nicolás. Si, he probado. Según he leído, he de poner el script al inicio de la pagina para que se auto-ejecute pero no hacía nada. Igual entendí algo mal.

Comment: No se si te estoy comprendiendo bien, pero deseas que al ejecutarse la vista, te haga click automaticamente, puedes desde javascript y jquery usando `$(document).ready(function () { $('#Create').click(); })`

Comment: Correcto Nicolás, eso es lo que andaba buscando. Voy a probar el método, gracias ;) !

Comment: Te he escrito una respuesta mas detallada sobre que es lo que ocurre

Answer (score 1):

En tu Vista puedes usar JavaScript para hacer llamadas al [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) como una web normal

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#crt').click(function(){
    alert('Click en el boton');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>     
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="crt" />
      </div>
    </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

He simplificado tu código a simplemente el boton, si quieres que automaticamente sea clicado puedes usar este otro:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#crt').click(function(){
    alert('Click en el boton');
  });
  
  $('#crt').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>     
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="crt" />
      </div>
    </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Usando `$('#crt').click();` obligas a la pagina a clicar, con `$(document).ready(function(){//Codigo});` Le dices que en el momento que la página esté cargada ejecute el código de la función.
Ya desde ahí puedes enviar al controlador lo que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias Nicolás, funcionó a la perfección! Lo único, que se ve como cambia la pagina y acude a la vista de crear, aunque luego rápidamente me retorna a donde debe. Un saludo, muchas gracias!! ;)

Comment: Me alegro que haya sido de ayuda, si es la respuesta correcta puedes marcarla con el tic para que ambos recibamos reputación y pueda ayudar a otras personas en un futuro con tu mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

En la vista donde tienes el botón puedes hacer referencia al controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "ControllerName"))
    {
       <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="crt" />
    }
```

Haciendo referencia al fomulario y a continución en la en Controller devolver el formulario